# Serial output in input Buffer?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am bashing together a C# + WPF app to send serial data to my nixie clock.

I am having poor performance sending and receiving data using the C# app that I don't have when sending/receiving via a terminal program.

In my C# app, my serial output triggers the datareceivedhandler.  I do not get an echo when using a terminal program.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime aMoment = DateTime.Now;


    SerialPort aPort = (SerialPort)sender;



    // Because I am updating the UI from a thread other than the main thread.
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {

        string indata = aPort.ReadLine();
        string outData = aMoment.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH':'mm':'ss.fff, ") + indata + Environment.NewLine;


        if (chkEnableDatalog.IsChecked == true)
            File.AppendAllText(@txtDatalogPath.Text, outData);

        txtSerialIn.Text = indata;
        txtDataLogLine.Text = outData;

        txtSerialOutHistory.AppendText("<" + indata);

        outData = "";
        indata = "";

    }));
}
```

Sometimes the delay for a serial response can be very long - many seconds - using a terminal app, I usually get the response right away.

Below is a screenshot from my c# app.  The "<" signifies data received thru the datareceivedhandler.  other lines are outputs.  A valid response from my clock for "hours?" is "hours:nn" where nn is an integer 1::23.

Also below, you can see a terminal program displaying data from serial requests as expected.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/bJXeV]

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of issue is very hard to debug from a purely software side. If you plan to use serial often, a digital logic analyzer can be an invaluable tool for seeing exactly what and when data is being transmitted.

I've done quite a bit of C# serial coms, and I've never had any C# induced latency issues.

Comment: Do you know what is the last character coming from your Clock which shows the end of the line?

Comment: The last thing the clock sends after a value is "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

Read the data first then in the current thread, then call invoke to update UI

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime aMoment = DateTime.Now;

```
SerialPort aPort = (SerialPort)sender;
string indata = aPort.ReadLine(); <<<-- Read data before invoke.


// Because I am updating the UI from a thread other than the main thread.
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)((indata ) =>
{

    string outData = aMoment.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH':'mm':'ss.fff, ") + indata + Environment.NewLine;


    if (chkEnableDatalog.IsChecked == true)
        File.AppendAllText(@txtDatalogPath.Text, outData);

    txtSerialIn.Text = indata;
    txtDataLogLine.Text = outData;

    txtSerialOutHistory.AppendText("<" + indata);

    outData = "";
    indata = "";

}));
```

}

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point to an example of this? I'm pretty green in C#.